# Why java method is not working in loop

Tags: java, class, for-loop

This is code to find armstorm numbers between given intervals. But when I put my my method in loop in main method so that it can run between given interval, then the loop only run one time and don't change the value passed to method. Why this is so? Is there is a difference in working of these conditions in different languages?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ArmstormNumbers {
    int mod, div, count = 0, rev = 0, pow = 1, sum = 0;
    int checkArm(int num) {
        while(num!=0) {
            mod = num%10;
            div = num/10;
            num = div;
            count++;
            rev = (rev*10) + mod;
        }

        while(rev!=0) {
            mod = rev%10;
            div = rev/10;
            rev = div;
            int temp = mod;
            for(pow = 1; pow < count; pow++) {
                mod = mod * temp;
            }
            sum=sum+(mod);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num, arms, inp, fp, asm, num2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArmstormNumbers object = new ArmstormNumbers();
        System.out.println("This program will find armstorm numbers between two intervels");
        System.out.println("Input Initial point ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Final Point");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        int temp = num;

        for(num = temp; num <= num2; num++) {
            asm = object.checkArm(num);
            if(asm == num)  {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `div=rev/10` if `rev` is less than 10, this will give 0 as it is a division between integers (which gives an integer result). Is this what you want?

Comment: This looks like it should be inside the method to declare and init local variables `int mod,div,count=0,rev=0,pow=1,sum=0;` try moving it two lines down.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes It worked When I put these Variables in the method. Thanks!! Can you explain me lil' bit more why Those variables have to be declared in method? Why this worked now? I'm actually new to JAVA. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the variable declarations so that they become method-local variables which get initialised each time the method is executed, instead of only once when instantiating the object.

I.e. change

```
int mod,div,count=0,rev=0,pow=1,sum=0;
int CheckArm(int num)
{
```

to

```
int CheckArm(int num)
{
    int mod,div,count=0,rev=0,pow=1,sum=0;
```

The problem you have and which you solve that way is probably relying on sum being 0 at start but not making that sure.